# Android - Update app with new APK sign error

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, google-play-console, android-app-signing

Long story short: 2 years ago I had someone create a app for me, this was coded in Xamrian and uploaded through AppCenter.ms(I think). Now, 2 years later I want to update that app. I rewrote the whole app in Java using Android Studio, and I am trying to upload a new version of the app in Google Play Console. I am trying to upload a signed apk, by using `Generate Signed Bundle / APK`. The problem is that I do not have the "key store" from the first upload, so when trying to upload the new apk(with a new keystore), this is what happens.

Error message:

```
You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_SIGNATURES: No JAR signatures.
```

What can I do about this? Is there any workaround so I can upload a new version of my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can not update an app with an APK / App Bundle which is signed with a different key.

The Google Play Store will prevent the upload.

If you try to install it locally over an existing app, Android will show an error (something like "App could not be installed").

Comment: Is there any way I can find it, or it this something the developer only has saved locally on their computer?

Comment: It's something that the original developer must give you. If you're lucky, the keystore and passwords were saved together with the code in the repository (which is not advises). Besides that, you're out of luck.

Comment: I actually got the keyInfo and keyStore file now! And I have the Keystore Alias and Password. Do I need anything else?

Comment: @Catalus1 You need the file, the keystore password and the key password. Often times, developers will use the same password for both. Looks like you have all you need.